# Dynamic Change - Google Chart Type

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pygooglechart, google-pie-chart

Depends on the select type, the chart should display. I prepared JSON. But I need to change chart type dynamically.

I tried differently. But got an error. Is there any alternative solution is available to fulfil this senorio.

JS Code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']}); 

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded. 
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); 

function drawChart() { 
  .......
  var chartType = document.getElementById("chartType").value;
  var chartTypeContent = "new google.visualization." + chartType + "(document.getElementById('chart_div'))";
  var chart =  chartTypeContent ; 
  chart.draw(data, options_fullStacked); 
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<select id="chartType" onchange="drawChart()">
<option value="ColumnChart">Column Chart</option>
<option value="BarChart">Bar Chart</option>
</select>
```

Error is: **Uncaught TypeError: chart.draw is not a function**

I'm new to google chart. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the error's description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it like this...

```
var chartTypeContent = new google.visualization[chartType](document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```