# Is it possible to pass a variable to new google.visualization constructor?

Tags: google-visualization

I am willing to draw Google Chart with a variable in the constructor.

Example:

```
    var chartType = 'BarChart';
    var chartTypeToDraw = new google.visualization.chartType(document.getElementById('chart'));
```

Is there a way to draw it based on defined chartType variable?

Comment: yes, see the answer here --> [Dynamic Change - Google Chart Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161527/dynamic-change-google-chart-type)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to access a property by name, use brackets instead of `.name`...

```
var chartType = 'BarChart';
var chartTypeToDraw = new google.visualization[chartType](document.getElementById('chart'));
```

Comment: using the [`ChartWrapper` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44440856/5090771) is another option...